# Flutter - Iterate chart with json

Tags: charts, dart, flutter

I'm trying to show a chart with a api json data. I made some a iteration and save result on a global variable, then i put this variable in chart, but variable return null, does not have any data. If i print list in foreach has data but if I print in  widget is null. I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51739064/flutter-json-and-time-series-charts/51763976) but code looks very different so i can´t follow.

Variables

```
  List<charts.Series<TimeSeriesSales, DateTime>> seriesList;
  List<TimeSeriesSales> data = [];
```

Get data

```
final String url = 'URL';

class TimeSeriesSales {
  final DateTime fecha;
  final double valor;

  TimeSeriesSales(this.fecha, this.valor);
}


 Future<Null> getUserDetails() async {
    final response = await http.get(
      url,
      headers: {
        HttpHeaders.authorizationHeader:
            "HEADER "
      },
    );
    final responseJson = json.decode(response.body);   
      setState(() {
      for (Map user in responseJson) {
          var fecha= new DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(user['fecha']).toLocal();
          data.add(TimeSeriesSales(new DateTime(fecha.year, fecha.month,fecha.day), user['valor']));
          print (data.toString());
      }
    });
  }
```

Init State

```
void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getUserDetails();
    seriesList = _createSampleData();
    animate = false;
     }
```

Fill TimeSeries

```
 List<charts.Series<TimeSeriesSales, DateTime>> _createSampleData() {
    return [
      new charts.Series<TimeSeriesSales, DateTime>(
        id: 'Sales',
        colorFn: (_, __) => charts.MaterialPalette.blue.shadeDefault,
        domainFn: (TimeSeriesSales valor, _) => valor.fecha,
        measureFn: (TimeSeriesSales valor, _) => valor.valor,
        data: data,
      )
    ];
  }
}
```

Widget

```
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
   new Expanded(
          child: new charts.TimeSeriesChart(
            seriesList,
            animate: animate,
            defaultRenderer: new charts.BarRendererConfig<DateTime>(),
            domainAxis: new charts.DateTimeAxisSpec(usingBarRenderer: true),
            defaultInteractions: false,
            behaviors: [
              new charts.SelectNearest(),
              new charts.DomainHighlighter()
            ],
          ),
        ),

)
```

Anybody knows why list does not have data in widget? And somebody know what is the right way to iterate chart on init?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You aren't re-creating the series after you've fetched and parsed the data. Call `seriesList = _createSampleData();` again after iterating the `responseData`, inside the `setState`.